# WinApi. Резерв номера порта

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Возможно ли зарезервировать диапазон/набор сетевых tcp портов таким образом, чтобы доступ (listen/read/write/accept) к ним мог иметь строго определенный процесс?
Резервация должна быть перманентной, т.е. сохраняться после перезапуска системы.
Все остальные процессы должны не иметь возможности что-либо делать на указанных сокетах

На данный момент было найдено
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-createpersistenttcpportreservation, но я как я понимаю эта функция резервирует в рамках процесса, что не подходит для задачи

Есть еще конфигурация через netsh динамического диапазона
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254330/reserve-a-tcp-port-in-windows, но тут порты просто исключаются из динамического диапазона, что тоже не совсем то.

P.S. я так пониаю, что это можно сконфигурировать через файрволл, но может ли виндовый стандартный файрволл конфигурироваться из кода и насколько это удобно/надёжно?

Comment: Вы `CreatePersistentTcpPortReservation` проверили в использовании?

Comment: @alexolut, пока нет, зондирую почву